# Get TextRange of the current word at caret

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textrange

I am new to WPF and currently I am studying to create a Sublime Text that has syntax highlighting. I come to a challenge in figuring out the TextRange of word at current caret position (Not include symbols e.g: **for(** will return the whole word instead of **for** only). More over because already solutions are checking the whole file which could be reduce the performance considerably. Are there any solution for this problems thank you! Below is my code

```
private TextRange getCurrentWordRange()
    {
        
        List<string> spaces = new List<string> { " ", "\t" ,";","(", ")", "=" };
        List<string> symbols=new List<string>{};

        TextPointer current = richTextBox.CaretPosition;
        TextPointer start = current, end = current;

        //Traverse to get the start of word
        while (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1), start); // get the textRange of the previous start

            if (spaces.Any(token => textRange.Text.Contains(token))) // check if textRange.Text has token that inside spaces
                break;
            else
                start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);
            
        }


        //Traverse to get the end of word
        while(end.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward)==TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(end,end.GetPositionAtOffset(1)); // get the textRange of the next start
            
            if (spaces.Any(token => textRange.Text.Contains(token)))
                break;
            else
                end = end.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
        }
        
        return new TextRange(start,end);
    }
```

**EDIT**
Fortunately, I rethink and writing the below code that might be success in the case. Hope anyone can check if it is correct. Thank you.

```
    private TextRange getCurrentWordRange()
        {
            List<string> spaces = new List<string> { " ", "\t" };
            List<string> symbols = new List<string> { ";", "(", ")", "=", "<", ">", "\"", ",", ".", "[", "]", ":" };
            TextPointer current = richTextBox.CaretPosition;
            TextPointer start = current, end = current;
            TextRange backward;
            TextRange forward;

            // check if start and end are not the Content.Start and Content.End
            if (start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1) == null)
                backward = new TextRange(start, start);
            else
                backward = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1), start);

            if (end.GetPositionAtOffset(1) == null)
                forward = new TextRange(end, end);
            else
                forward = new TextRange(end, end.GetPositionAtOffset(1));



            while (!spaces.Contains(backward.Text) && start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) == TextPointerContext.Text && !symbols.Contains(backward.Text))
            {
                start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);
                backward = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1));
            }
            while (!spaces.Contains(forward.Text) && end.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text && !symbols.Contains(forward.Text))
            {
                end = end.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
                forward = new TextRange(end, end.GetPositionAtOffset(1));
            }

            // if between start and end is "" then consider add a left adjacent or right adjacent symbol for further development
            if (new TextRange(start, end).Text == "")
            {
                if (symbols.Contains(backward.Text))
                {
                    start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);
                }
                else if (symbols.Contains(forward.Text))
                {
                    end = end.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);
                }
            }

            return new TextRange(start, end);
}
```

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrJgo.png)

I created a TextChanged Event for RTB then perform few functions to check and highlight keyword
It work great with @Jackdaw solution but stuck at that case again

Comment: You could use Regex, but you will either pass to it the entire text again, or you will still have to find start and end indexes yourself.

Comment: For highlighting purpose, it would be time consuming if i pass the text while Text is changed. I think I should do it by myself instead. Anyway thank you

Comment: @Totomaru: Look at the following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187764/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187764/6630084).

Comment: @Totomaru: The function above `getCurrentWordRange()` will not work correctly when words have partial formatting. But the `GetEdgeTextPointer()` function from the [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187764/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187764/6630084) post is supporting the partial formatting also.

Comment: @Jackdaw thank you I will check it if there is a solution for this.

Comment: @Totomaru: Any further question on your post is welcome! :)