# RichTextBox get full word after clicking on it with the mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How to get the whole word on click?
I know that similar questions have already been and I looked, but for some reason there are strange and very old solutions for 40 lines of code. Maybe there is something more modern?

Comment: For the `RichTextBox` control that has several _inlines_ types and they should be analyzed while scanning, the 40 lines code is not so bad solution. Can you at least show us this code, so we will try to improve it?

Comment: @Jackdaw Thank you for paying attention to the question. I read the MSDN documentation, got familiar with the subject area and found out that the RichTextBox is useless in 2021. This is the same unnecessary component as WebBrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how to get a word on the current caret position in the `RichTextBox` control.

The XAML:

```
<Window ... >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="rtb" AllowDrop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="2"
                    PreviewMouseUp="rtb_PreviewMouseUp" >
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Left" >

                   <!-- The RichTextBox control content should defined be here
                        or use the PASTE command to add some content... -->

                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox> 
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click">Mark Current Word</Button>                   
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The function below gets a pointer to the position from which the text is parsed in the specified direction to detect a word boundary. The `pattern` variable defines set of possible a word delimiters.

```
public static class TextPointerExt
{
    public static TextPointer GetEdgeTextPointer(this TextPointer position, LogicalDirection direction)
    {
        string pattern = @" ,;.!""?"; // Delimiters 
        int step = direction == LogicalDirection.Forward ? 1 : -1;    
        for (; position != null;)
        {
            var text = position.GetTextInRun(direction);    
            int offset = 0;
            int i = direction == LogicalDirection.Forward ? 0 : text.Length - 1;

            for (; i >= 0 && i < text.Length; offset++, i += step)
            {
                if (pattern.Contains(text[i]))
                {
                    return position.GetPositionAtOffset(offset * step, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                }
            }

            position = position.GetPositionAtOffset(offset * step, LogicalDirection.Forward);
            for (TextPointer latest = position; ;)
            {
                if ((position = position.GetNextContextPosition(direction)) == null)
                    return latest;

                var context = position.GetPointerContext(direction);
                var adjacent = position.GetAdjacentElement(direction);    
                if (context == TextPointerContext.Text)
                {
                    if (position.GetTextInRun(direction).Length > 0)
                        break;
                }
                else if (context == TextPointerContext.ElementStart && adjacent is Paragraph)
                {
                    return latest;
                }
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

Example of using the `GetEdgeTextPointer()` method to determine the current pointed word:

```
public void GetCurrentWord()
{          
    TextPointer current = rtb.CaretPosition;
    var start = current.GetEdgeTextPointer(LogicalDirection.Backward); // Word position before caret
    var end = current.GetEdgeTextPointer(LogicalDirection.Forward); // Word position after caret

    if (start is TextPointer && end is TextPointer && start.CompareTo(end) != 0)
    {
        TextRange textrange = new TextRange(start, end);
        // Print the found word to the debug window.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textrange.Text);

        // Select the found word
        rtb.Selection.Select(start, end);
    }
    rtb.Focus();
}

private void rtb_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    GetCurrentWord();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GetCurrentWord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event `PreviewMouseDown` to select the whole word. Of course, depending on the function you want, you can use similar events

```
private void richTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextSelection ts = richTextBox.Selection;
    string text = ts.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```